# What should happen (and what does happen) when you transfer a cNFT to an invalid address?

Tags: cnft

When transferring a cNFT to an invalid address the transaction succeeded. I feel like this shouldn't be allowed.

As far as I can tell *a new wallet/owner was created*, that was not the address that was transferred to.

Can I confirm, is this expected behaviour today?

**Invalid address used (another cNFT in the wallet, instead of actual wallet):** 112DK5o8D9Ev8wKokDxg28RB4NdDiUqFRUbWcY4jBrbBacGarTYt

**Transfer transaction:**
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5FAP813t7sKbTW312f5ksFtfzo2vSdC4Pk63m18M3Br446MKjGD4FdQpuVqXPo9A25oNovb9tJWaLk3Ds5BsMqHo

**New owner? - Only one transaction:** https://explorer.solana.com/address/BkDKjumbuVxDJnVH9tXfZd8ywH6tyzxVsMVzyhPJy73c

I have tried to transfer it, signed by the host wallet but get `"error": "unknown signer: 4m1da92mj.....`